# Using a Dependency Property in a Data Trigger

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, dependency-properties, datatrigger

I have the following custom control:

```
public class AnimatedButton : Button
    {
        public enum ButtonStates
        {
            None,
            Busy
        }

        public ButtonStates State
        {
            get { return (ButtonStates)GetValue(StateProperty); }
            set { SetValue(StateProperty, value); }
        }

        // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for State.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
        public static readonly DependencyProperty StateProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("State", typeof(ButtonStates), typeof(AnimatedButton), new PropertyMetadata(ButtonStates.None));

        public ImageSource ImageDefault
        {
            get { return (ImageSource)GetValue(ImageDefaultProperty); }
            set { SetValue(ImageDefaultProperty, value); }
        }

        // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for ImageDefault.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
        public static readonly DependencyProperty ImageDefaultProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("ImageDefault", typeof(ImageSource), typeof(AnimatedButton), new PropertyMetadata(null));

        public ImageSource ImageBusy
        {
            get { return (ImageSource)GetValue(ImageBusyProperty); }
            set { SetValue(ImageBusyProperty, value); }
        }

        ...
    }
```

My aim here is to display the appropriate image source based on the current button state. For example, if the ButtonState is **None**, then display the default image, otherwise display the **Busy** image, pretty straightforward. Here is the style:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type controls:AnimatedButton}">
    ...
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type controls:AnimatedButton}">
                <Border>
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                        <Image x:Name="img"/>

                        <TextBlock Text="{TemplateBinding Content}"
                                   Grid.Column="1"/>
                    </Grid>
                </Border>

                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding State}" Value="None">
                        <Setter TargetName="img" Property="Source" Value="{Binding ImageDefault}"/>
                    </DataTrigger>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding State}" Value="Busy">
                        <Setter TargetName="img" Property="Source" Value="{Binding ImageBusy}"/>
                    </DataTrigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

The problem is in the **DataTrigger**, it isn't picking up the dependency property **State**. After adding the control onto a view, I am receiving the following error in the Output:

```
System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: 'State' property not found on 'object' ''WorkspaceViewModel' (HashCode=56037929)'. BindingExpression:Path=State; DataItem='WorkspaceViewModel' (HashCode=56037929); target element is 'AnimatedButton' (Name=''); target property is 'NoTarget' (type 'Object')
```

Reading that error message, it appears as though it's looking for the **State** property on the **WorkspaceViewModel** as opposed to the control that the dependency property belongs to. Why is this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Bindings in the DataTriggers (correctly) expect the State property to be in the DataContext of the control. But you want to trigger on the value of a property of the control itself.

You should therefore use Triggers instead of DataTriggers:

```
<ControlTemplate.Triggers>
    <Trigger Property="State" Value="None">
        <Setter TargetName="img" Property="Source"
            Value="{Binding ImageDefault, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"/>
    </Trigger>
    <Trigger Property="State" Value="Busy">
        <Setter TargetName="img" Property="Source"
            Value="{Binding ImageBusy, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"/>
    </Trigger>
</ControlTemplate.Triggers>
```